# PushNotificationIOS.requestPermissions() callback

Tags: react-native

I don't want to ask my users to allow notifications before they actually need them in the app.

So when a user schedules a local notification in my app I want to request notification permissions and if the user accepts then set the local notification.
The problem is that there doesn't seem to be any callback for `PushNotificationIOS.requestPermissions()`, meaning that if I call `PushNotificationIOS.checkPermissions()` right after it will run before the user has tabbed the alert window and return `0` in the permissions object, even though the user might accept.

So my question is if there is any way to request permissions and subsequently set a notification, or do I have to request permissions before I actually need to use them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The release notes for v0.28-rc has just been published and one of the new features is that `PushNotificationIOS.requestPermissions()` has been promisified, which is exactly what I needed. See the commit [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/f4dbf37ba85acb988bbb26e339ea7f7536b1f931).

Comment: Does that mean I can use it like so: `PushNotificationIOS.requestPermissions()
    .then((permissions) => console.log(permissions));`

What am I missing? This doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Testing on 0.28, I can't get the promises to fire either.

Comment: Tested on .31 same issue, You can add your comment here https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/f4dbf37ba85acb988bbb26e339ea7f7536b1f931#commitcomment-18831421

Comment: I finally got the Promise responding correctly. There's a bug in React Native that requires you to register an event listener before the promise resolves. See my write up here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/9105

Answer (score 3):

There is the option to add an event listener for when a device registers for push notifications.

```
PushNotificationIOS.addEventListener('register', this._onPushNotificationRegistration);
```

When you attempt to schedule your local notification you can check the permissions at that point and if you don't have permission yet, you could request them.

```
_prepareNotification(alertBody, soundName, badge) {
    let notification = {
      alertBody: alertBody,
      applicationIconBadgeNumber: badge,
      fireDate: new Date(Date.now() + (1000 * 10)).getTime(), // 10 seconds in the future
      soundName: soundName
    };

    PushNotificationIOS.checkPermissions((permissions) => {
      if (permissions.alert) {
        this._scheduleNotification(notification);
      } else {
        this._requestNotificationPermissions(notification);
      }
    });
}
```

When you request permissions, store the notification that you want to send in your state.

```
_requestNotificationPermissions(notification) {
  this.setState({
    notificationToPost: notification
  });

  PushNotificationIOS.requestPermissions();
}
```

When the user allows you to send them notifications, then schedule it in the registration response.

```
_onPushNotificationRegistration(token) {
  console.log('Registered for notifications', token);

  if (this.state.notificationToPost) {
    this._scheduleNotification(this.state.notificationToPost);
  }
}
```

This is a rough example of how you might achieve what you require, I am sure that there are nuances around you application state that this doesn't cover, but hopefully it will give you some ideas.

I have put some of these ideas into a sample application that you can have a look at https://github.com/AidenMontgomery/react-native-sample.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comprehensive answer, however I just saw that as of 0.28 `PushNotificationIOS.requestPermissions()` will return a promise so that seems it is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @David how did you get the promise to work? I'm trying to use it like so:

`PushNotificationIOS.requestPermissions().then((permissions) => console.log(permissions));`

but that doesn't ever fire the console.log. What am I missing?

Comment: I never got around to test it so I can't tell you why that does not work - it looks correct to me.